# React state saving first value empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I have the following setup in my react app:

```
  const [modalReasonInput, setModalReasonInput] = useState("")

  const validateReason = () => {
  console.log(modalReasonInput)
  if (modalReasonInput === "" && record.judgement_result === "fail") {
      setError("Field is required")
      return false
  }
   setError("")
   return true
 }

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setModalReasonInput(value)
    validateReason()
  }


    <TextField
      type="textarea"
      maxLength={1000}
      showCounting
      rows={6}
      value={modalReasonInput}
      onBlur={() => validateReason()}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}
    />
```

With the above code when I enter first character in the input field a blank/white space is set as value to state `modalReasonInput`.

The value is set only if I type another character, but value is set to first character I had typed.

Due to this my validation is failing while typing first character.

How can I update the state value as I type.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is `TextField` a custom component or a UI library?

Comment: UI library `ant-d`

Answer (score 2):

It is getting updated as you type but when you try to `console.log` the state right after you call `setModalReasonInput` you can't see it right away because state updates in React is asynchronous. You can check the state with `useEffect` as the state changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(modalReasonInput)
}, [modalReasonInput])
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your `handleChange` function. If you set the state and perform a validation shortly after it is not guaranteed that the state is available in the next line.

```
  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setModalReasonInput(value)
    validateReason()         // value not guarenteed to be in modalReasonInput state
  }
```

You can either separate state update and validation or directly pass in your value to your validation function `validateReason()`:

```
  const validateReason = (value) => {
    console.log(value)
    if (value === "" && record.judgement_result === "fail") {
      setError("Field is required")
      return false
    }
    setError("")
    return true
  };
```

```
  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setModalReasonInput(value)
    validateReason(value)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [modalReasonInput, setModalReasonInput] = useState("")
  const reasonRef = useRef("")

  const validateReason = () => {
  console.log(easonRef.current)
  if (reasonRef.current === "" && record.judgement_result === "fail") {
      setError("Field is required")
      return false
  }
   setError("")
   return true
 }

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setModalReasonInput(value)
    easonRef.current = value
    validateReason()
  }
```

Thanks everyone I ended up using `useRef` hook for this issue. I didn't use @sm3sher approach because `validateReason` is being called by other methods also which do not get event value.

I didn't use @Enes method `useEffect` because `judgement_result` is initially set to null.